# SQL Server Query to carry over values from previous day when no current day values exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, gaps-and-islands

I have a query that tracks a traders capital at risk for each trading session. When there are no trades on a given day I need to carry over the End-Of-Day values from the the last active day, until the next active day. This is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME = '2019-08-20'
DECLARE @End   DATETIME = '2019-08-27'

DECLARE @history TABLE( Id INT, AccountId INT, AllocatedCapital MONEY, RunningAllocatedCapital MONEY,RN INT,SessionDate DATETIME) 

INSERT INTO @history(Id, AccountId, AllocatedCapital, RunningAllocatedCapital,RN,SessionDate) 
     VALUES (362082,    1182,   -170150.0000,   -170150.0000,   1,  '2019-08-20'),
            (362090,    1182,   -4167.9600,     -199466.4600,   1,  '2019-08-21'),
            (362088,    1182,   -10330.0000,    -195298.5000,   2,  '2019-08-21'),
            (362086,    1182,   -9454.5000,     -184968.5000,   3,  '2019-08-21'),
            (362084,    1182,   -5364.0000,     -175514.0000,   4,  '2019-08-21'),
            (362094,    1182,   -4140.0000,     -203606.4600,   1,  '2019-08-22'),
            (362092,    1182,   -4140.0000,     -207746.4600,   2,  '2019-08-22'),
            (362105,    1182,    4140.0000,     -187052.4800,   1,  '2019-08-27')


;WITH tradingdays  as (

SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @Start, @End) + 1)
       DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1,@Start) SessionDate 
  FROM sys.all_objects a
 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b

)

SELECT -MIN(RunningAllocatedCapital) MaxCapitalAtRisk,
       -MAX(CASE H.RN WHEN 1 THEN H.RunningAllocatedCapital END)EodCapitalAtRisk,
        C.SessionDate
  FROM tradingdays C
  LEFT JOIN @history H ON H.SessionDate = C.SessionDate
 WHERE DATENAME(dw,C.SessionDate) NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
 GROUP BY C.SessionDate, H.SessionDate
 ORDER BY C.SessionDate
```

Instead of this:

```
MaxCapitalAtRisk    EodCapitalAtRisk    SessionDate
170150.00           170150.00           2019-08-20 00:00:00.000
199466.46           199466.46           2019-08-21 00:00:00.000
207746.46           203606.4600         2019-08-22 00:00:00.000
NULL                NULL                2019-08-23 00:00:00.000
NULL                NULL                2019-08-26 00:00:00.000
187052.48           187052.48           2019-08-27 00:00:00.000
```

My Result set should look like this:

```
MaxCapitalAtRisk    EodCapitalAtRisk    SessionDate
170150.00           170150.00           2019-08-20 00:00:00.000
199466.46           199466.46           2019-08-21 00:00:00.000
207746.46           203606.46           2019-08-22 00:00:00.000
203606.46           203606.46           2019-08-23 00:00:00.000
203606.46           203606.46           2019-08-26 00:00:00.000
187052.48           187052.48           2019-08-27 00:00:00.000
```

I know there are clean ways to do this in SQL Server without using sub queries or cursors, but I don't recall how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are looking for `lag()` with the `ignore nulls` option. SQL Server does not support that, but we can emulate it with a gaps-and-island technique.

The idea is to build groups of records made of one "regular" record (the island) followed by 0 to N "missing" recods (the gaps), using a conditional sum or count. Then, we can use `first_value()` to fill the gaps with the value of the island:

```
with tradingdays as (
    select @start SessionDate 
    union all select dateadd(day, 1, SessionDate) from tradingdays where SessionDate < @end
)
select
    SessionDate,
    first_value(MaxCapitalAtRisk) over(partition by grp order by SessionDate) MaxCapitalAtRisk,
    first_value(EodCapitalAtRisk) over(partition by grp order by SessionDate) EodCapitalAtRisk
from (
    select 
        td.SessionDate, 
        - min(RunningAllocatedCapital) MaxCapitalAtRisk,
        - max(case h.rn when 1 then h.runningallocatedcapital end) EodCapitalAtRisk,
        count(h.SessionDate) over(order by td.SessionDate) grp
    from tradingdays td 
    left join @history h on h.SessionDate = td.SessionDate 
    where datename(dw, td.SessionDate) not in ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
    group by td.SessionDate, h.SessionDate
) t
order by SessionDate
```

I changed the common table expression that generates the dates to use recursion, because I find it easier to follow - but that does not change the logic, you can switch back to your original cte if you like it better. If you stick to my cte, and your dates spread over more that 100 days, then you need to add `option(maxrecursion 0)` at the very end of the query.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9d3dd27fff7b99046e983e3892ca8a88)**:

```
SessionDate             | MaxCapitalAtRisk | EodCapitalAtRisk
:---------------------- | :--------------- | :---------------
2019-08-20 00:00:00.000 | 170150.0000      | 170150.0000     
2019-08-21 00:00:00.000 | 199466.4600      | 199466.4600     
2019-08-22 00:00:00.000 | 207746.4600      | 207746.4600     
2019-08-23 00:00:00.000 | 207746.4600      | 207746.4600     
2019-08-26 00:00:00.000 | 207746.4600      | 207746.4600     
2019-08-27 00:00:00.000 | 187052.4800      | 187052.4800
```

Comment: I didn't provide a thorough enough example data set. When there is a gap I need to insert the previous EodCapitalAtRisk in both fields. When there is no trading on a particular day MaxCapitalAtRisk is the previous EodCapitalAtRisk. Hopefully its easy enough to modify the query you provided.